# Replace angle brackets in Javascript string?

Tags: javascript, string

Hi I have a string like below:

```
 >123456<
```

How can I easily replace the angle brackets and replace them with blank?

I have tried the below:

```
                        mystring.replace(/>/g, "");
                        mystring.replace(/</g, "");
```

However if I do an `alert(mystring);` on this it is still showing with the angle brackets?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to assign, in this case, `mystring` with the result of the operation.

```
var s = '>123456789<';
s = s.replace(/[<>]/g, '');
alert(s);
```

Comment: mystring.replace(/[&\/\\#+()$~%'":*?<>{}\\|]/g,'')

Comment: +1 for cleaner solution

Comment: Cheers - will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting it back to the string:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/>/g, "");
mystring = mystring.replace(/</g, "");
```

---

As in Zanathel's answer, use a single regex for this `[<>]` thats cleaner than 2 statements.

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/[<>]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/>|</g, '')
```

Comment: This is even more cleaner, reduce one char further. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
var xx =">123456<";
alert(xx.replace(">","").replace("<",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript strings are immutable. Therefore, every time you make change to string a new string object is created.

This will work fine:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/>/g, "");
mystring = mystring.replace(/</g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. It worked for me:

```
var str = ">123456<";
var ne = str.replace(">", "");
ne = ne.replace("<", "");

alert(ne);
```